# Программа компилируется но не запускается Си

Tags: c, c++

Программа должна считывать из input строку и менять там слова на числа, но при запуске появляется ошибка и output пустой. Появляется ошибка

> Debug Assertion Failed. Expression
> (stream !=NULL) File:
> f:\dd\vctools/crty_bld/self_x86\crt\src\fclose.c
> Line 47

Пользуюсь Visual C++2008. Как я понял ругается на эти куски, весь код не влез сюда
залил на http://pastebin.com/SUjcJCxn

Comment: @xameleon48, а на http://pastebin.com/SUjcJCxn. мне пишет 

     This paste has been removed!

Думаю, стоит подправить текст вопроса, убрав точку в конце урла.

--

Почитал немного (убрав точку). 

@xameleon48, думаю это все лучше с самого начала переписать, обязательно с комментариями в начале, поясняющими, а что собственно должна программа делать

(лучше на чистом Си, как @KoVadim советует, а если есть возможность, то и не в винде, а в любом \*nix).

Comment: так вообще задание
Задание:В исходном файле содержится некоторый текст. Разработать программу, которая заменяет все словесные записи денежных сумм числами. При этом возможны следующие варианты замены: 
- заменять/не заменять «руб.» на «рублей»;
- заменять/не заменять «коп.» на «копеек».

не знаю, может это можно и легче реализовать без этой мороки?

Comment: Понятно. 

У меня ощущение, что используемые там структуры данных слегка не адекватны задаче.

По сути Вам надо читать текст по словам и запоминать границы слов. Скорее всего надо запоминать несколько последних (сразу не соображу, ну скажем 20 слов). Когда выходите за эту границу -- предыдущий текст можно отправлять в вывод без изменений.

Как только нашли упоминание денег (рубли, копейки) надо проанализировать прочитанные слова, заменить (нужные) на число (остальные вывести) и вывести число, а потом руб., коп и т.п. 

Обратите вниение, что кроме слов *запоминать надо и символы между ними*.

Comment: Что то не пойму как делать,
мне тут скинули вот такой код но он тоже что не работает компилит вроде норм все , но числа не меняет
http://pastebin.com/Zzq6UqS2

Answer (score 3):

Падает оно в `pload_lists` в строке 147. Потому как файл не был открыт в строке 139 (видимо ввиду отсутствия такового).

Но фишка в том, что код не компилируется - он кривоват. Правда майкрософтвоский компилятор видимо переварил и не поперхнулся.

Например, Вы пытаетесь распечатать вот таким кодом

```
std::string line;
//....
printf("%s", line);
```

для с++ лучше использовать cout. Но если сильно хочется, тогда нужно так

```
printf("%s", line.c_str());
```

и таких ошибок по коду тоны. Может уже напишете просто на чистом с?

Comment: а на чистом си и надо, просто некоторые куски мне помогали, а сейчас связаться с тем кто помогал не могу

Comment: переписать можно, на пару часов работы, но только код жуткий...

Comment: т.е получилось , что тут код вперемешку С и С++?

Comment: не то слово. Полный фарш. А некоторые места, это уже не си и не плюсы, а неведомая зверюшка.

Comment: @xameleon48, там ошибка на ошибке (в т.ч. и просто в логике).

Например, что именно *должна* (т.е. что *задумано*, а не что там *реализовано*) делать, функция `ParseString()`, я так и не понял.

А, скажем, `read_line()` -- просто прочесть строку (*тогда почему бы просто не вызвать* `fgets()`)? Или что-то еще делать?

Comment: @avp может тогда, лучше как нибудь по другому реализовать , замену денежных сумм числом, без файла с заменами?

Comment: @KoVadim вы говорили что можно будет переписать код, а сможете до завтра вечере, конечно же за вознаграждение 
Пишите на почту xameleone48@gmail.com

Comment: а разве я сказал, что именно я собираюсь его переписать?

Answer (score 2):

Суть проблемы видна в этих строчках:

```
FILE* f = fopen(file_data,"r");
FILE* fo = fopen(file_output,"w");
while (!feof(f))
{
    read_line(f,&line);
    /* ... */
    fprintf(fo, "\n");
}
fclose(f);
fclose(fo);
```

Проверка на корректность открытия `fo` и `f` где?

Comment: не совсем правильно:) Компилировать пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал - не собирается :) Виндов у меня нет, а g++ матерится сильно.